# Graphs in which the degree of every vertex is at least 3

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, trees

I have a trouble in proving the following:

If $G$ is a graph such that every vertex in it has degree greater than or equal to 3, then for any tree $T$ of $G$ the following is true:

$$|E(T)| \leq 2|E(G-T)|-3,$$

provided that $|E(G-T)| \geq 3.$

I tried to use the fact that the sum of degrees is equal to $2|E(G)|$ but couldn’t get a useful result.

Comment: What relations do you know between the number of edges and the number of vertices in a graph where each vertex has degree at least three? What relations do you know between the number of edges and the number of vertices of a tree? Can you use those relations in your question?

Comment: @GerryMyerson I'm not an expert in graph theory.. All I know that the number of edges in a Tree is $|V(G)|-1$.

Comment: OK. The immediate vicinity of each vertex is divided into regions by the edges leaving the vertex. Put a little pebble into each region. How many pebbles are there in the immediate vicinity of each vertex? How many pebbles total, adding up over all the vertices? Now, how many pebbles are there next to each edge? How many pebbles total, adding up over all the edges? Now you've got two different expressions for the number of pebbles, so you get a relation out of that. Mind you, I haven't worked out the details, I'm not sure it will answer the question, but it's always better to try something.

Comment: The idea is nice, but I’m not sure if I can get the desired inequality using it or not.. I tried but couldn’t get something useful..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $n_d$ be the number of vertices of degree $d$.  Then
$$|V(G)|=\sum_{d \ge 3} n_d$$
and
$$2|E(G)|=\sum_{d \ge 3} d n_d.$$
So
$$3|V(G)| = 3 \sum_{d \ge 3} n_d = \sum_{d \ge 3} 3 n_d \le \sum_{d \ge 3} d n_d = 2|E(G)|.$$
Subtract 3 from both sides to obtain
$$3(|V(G)|-1) \le 2|E(G)|-3.$$
Now $|E(T)|=|V(G)|-1$ implies that
$$3|E(T)| \le 2|E(G)|-3.$$
Finally, $|E(G-T)|=|E(G)|-|E(T)|$ yields
$$|E(T)| \le 2|E(G-T)|-3.$$

Comment: That's awesome! Thanks a lot.

Comment: Glad to help.  Please mark my answer as accepted.